# How to map a list of elements to a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of locations, extracted from geocoders. I want to map these locations to their respective Postal codes in DataFrame.
location = ['country', 'city', 'state', 'postal-code']
My data frame looks like this:

```
ID   postal code   
 1      1111
 2      2222
 3      3333
 4      4444
 5      5555
```

I want something like this:

```
ID   postal code   country  state  city
 1      1111         1        1      1
 2      2222         2        2      2 
 3      3333         3        3      3
 4      4444         4        4      4
 5      5555         5        5      5
```

Numbers represent the respective code, country, state, and city values.

Comment: are you splitting the postal code to fill the other columns?

Comment: Do you mean location? The postal code is already there in the frame and the list. I want to split the location list and match the postal code of the list to the frame and based on that make other columns (country, state, city).

Comment: Try looking at [How To Create a New Column Based on Values From Other Columns in Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-new-column-based-on-other-columns-pandas-5586d87de73d).

Comment: Where is the location list? Its not in the data shared. are the values under country, state, city from Location? your question need clarity

Answer (score 0):

Try df `apply()` method like this:

```
df[['country', 'city', 'state', 'postal-code']] = df['postal code'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]]))
```